# App Script Time Trigger with Condition (i was told impossible)

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, timestamp, multiple-conditions

I need to create a time trigger that requires 3 things.

- Runs every 60 minutes (originally set for 800, but needs to run more often)
- Only runs on rows that have been timestamped over 1 hour
- Only runs on a row if Col13 is TRUE

I have created a simple version that runs perfect, but i dont understand how to integrate with time conditions i need. (Row 2 is an example row, does not need to move)

```
function TimeTrigger(){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('MoveChecked')
   .timeBase()
   .atHour(8)
   .everyDays(1)
   .create();
}

function MoveChecked(){
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ss = sh.getSheetByName("Shipped_Log");
  const outSheet = sh.getSheetByName("Master_Adjustment_Log");
  let data = ss.getRange(2,1,ss.getLastRow()-1,23).getValues();
  let out = [];
  for (let i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
  if (data[i][11]== true){
    out.push(data[i]);
    ss.deleteRow(i+2);
    data.splice(i,1);
    i--;
  }
 }
outSheet.getRange(outSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,out.length,23).setValues(out);
}
```

[spreadsheet for context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS3I9.png)

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What are the time conditions that you need?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Only runs on rows that have been timestamped over 1 hour`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, about `Only runs on a row if Col13 is TRUE`, when I saw your provided image of your Spreadsheet, "Col13" is "Tracking#". Do you want to check whether the values of column "M" are existing? By the way, what means `i was told impossible`?

Answer (score 0):

#### Movechecked on a one hour trigger

I assumed timestamp is column 1 but it can be changed easily

```
function TimeTrigger() {
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "MoveChecked").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('MoveChecked').timeBased().everyHours(1).create()
  }
}

function MoveChecked() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Shipped_Log");
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Master_Adjustment_Log");
  let vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let dt = new Date();
  let thv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate(), dt.getHours() - 1).valueOf()
  let out = [];
  let d = 0;
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let ctv = new Date(r[0]).valueOf()
    if (r[12] == "TRUE" && ctv > thv) {
      out.push(r);
      sh.deleteRow(i + 2 - d++);
    }
  })
  osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, out.length, out[0].length).setValues(out);
}
```